# Call to a member function script() on string in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to render a chart through master layout and it is successfully rendering for my dashboard but it affects the rest of the sidebar menu. I can't access to other pages which using the same master layout as the dashboard because of this error.

I've applied the view composer in order to share the variable to all views.

This is the error message while I try to access the other pages which extend with the same master layout.

> Call to a member function script() on string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\MMSRBackend\resources\views\layouts\admin.blade.php)

This is the `AppServiceProvider.php`

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->alias('bugsnag.logger', \Illuminate\Contracts\Logging\Log::class);
        $this->app->alias('bugsnag.logger', \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);

        // View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        //     $view->with('chart', 'home');
        // });

        View::share('chart', 'home');

        // view()->share('chart', 'home');
    }
}
```

`admin.blade.php`

This is the master layout page, the following `{!! $chart->script() !!}` is not working.

```php
    <div class="app-body">
        @include('partials.menu')
        <main class="main">


            <div style="padding-top: 20px" class="container-fluid">

                @yield('content')

            </div>

        </main>


        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        {!! $chart->script() !!}
```

Is there anyone know how to solve this error ? 
Can anyone provide solutions regarding to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Error is telling you exactly what the problem is in this case, you trying to call the function on the string $chart:

**$chart = "home"** as set here **View::share('chart', 'home');**

Review [Laravel documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) for more details on *View::share*

Comment: May i know how to implement the solution ?

Comment: You probably need an instance of the class, 'usually' something like $chart = new Chart(args) and then call it from the service provider, View::share('chart', $chart); however I'd recommend doing it in a controller or view, just instantiating the class and use throughout your application

Comment: i have the instance of class created in a controller and I implemented View::share('chart', $chart) in a controller as you said but now it has another problem "Undefined variable: chart (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\MMSRBackend\resources\views\layouts\admin.blade.php)" when i try to access to other pages

Comment: if you're doing it inside a controller method you just need to pass it to the view (master if globally) using return view('name.of.view', compact('variable'))